# Deduplication solution for multiple offline database backups

Tags: database, duplicates, backup, nas, backup-strategies

I have multiple copies of the same database with size of several terabytes. I was looking for a solution where I could upload the very first backup and then, instead of uploading the same entire backup with only few megabytes of changes, only upload the blocks that have changed. I know this process is called deduplication, so I was wondering if there is a software that does that, possibly to be a built-in nas-management software solution, like `openmediavault`.

Comment: For those who are looking for a solution that meets the requirements mentioned above, check out https://restic.net/ and https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/LessFS .

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to solve this problem
I was also suffering from this problem.
but I found that how to use "BATCH" file

There are mainly 2 command

1. X_COPY
2. ROBO_COPY

According to your need here, (2)robo_copy will be helpfull

robocopy will backup your specific file or folder
even if you changed some megabytes data, it will only copy the new data
only your new blocks will be copy.

HOW TO DO

Open NotePad and type

```
robocopy "file path you want to copy" "on which folder you want to paste" /MIR
```

And then save your notepad as ".bat" file

for more help check out
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-robocopy-in-windows/